# VScode not picking up eslint.rc, but terminal is

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I am configuring a new application utilizing React and ESlint.  In my
`.eslintrc.js` file I am extending airbnb and overriding some of their rules like so.

```
.eslintrc.js
```

```
module.exports = {
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "cmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "jest",
    "styled-components-config"
  ],
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "arrow-body-style": "off",
    "arrow-parens": "off",
    "comma-dangle": "off",
    "consistent-return": "off",
    "eol-last": "error",
    "jsx-one-expression-per-line": "off",
  }
}
```

I get no errors in the terminal when I boot up my webpack dev server, but in my IDE (VSCode) It is still throwing me an error.

```
ConversationsCard.js
```

```
import React from 'react';

export const ConversationsCard = (props) => {
  const { number } = props;
  return (
    <li>Conversation {number}</li> // error here `Conversation ` must be placed on a new lineeslint(react/jsx-one-expression-per-line
  );
};
```

I don't have ESlint installed globally so it should should be looking at my `.eslintrc.js` . I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.  I've tried changing `"off"` to `0` and a few other things.  Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: what about changing the name to `.eslintrc` and installing the plugin in VSCode and modify eslintIntegration settings?

Comment: Anyone?  Still throwing me an error for the one JSX expression per line even though you can see I have it set to 'off' in my .eslintrc.js

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was I wasn't using the correct name for the rule.  ESLint was throwing an error for

`jsx-one-expression-per-line`

but when you declare the rule in your `.eslintrc.js` it should be declared like so

`"react/jsx-one-expression-per-line": "off",`